# Недосоздаются ячейки в js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем приветы. Есть код 
Кому лень читать их  вот ссылка на кодпен с удобным чтением кода
https://codepen.io/otdyhaem/pen/EbMVML

Проблема вот в чем , когда сначала добавляю суммы а потом сроки-тогда все норм, а вот когда добавляю суммы после сроков то со 2-го раза вдруг  начинает не хватать  ячеек для таблицы. Всё перерыл в коде не нашел ошибку. Может кто-нибудь указать на нее?)))

```js
var i = 1;
var i2 = 1;
var srabator = 0;
var tedeus = 1;
var cp = tedeus;
$("#ad").click(function() {
  var a = prompt("От скольких дней ?", 0);
  var b = prompt("До скольких дней?", 1);

  var something = parseInt(a) + 1;
  $('#srok' + i).after("<tr id ='srok" + (++i) + "'> <td id = 'srok" + i + "td" + i2 + "'> Ot " + a + "  do " + b + " dney</td" + "</tr>");
  for (i2 = 1; i2 < tedeus + 1; i2++) {
    $("#srok" + i + "td" + i2).after("<td id = 'srok" + i + "td" + (i2 + 1) + "'><input ></td>");
  }
  i2 = 1;


  /* $('#srok'+i).after('<tr id = "srok'+(++i)+'"><td>От 1 до '+a+' дней</td><td id = "td'+(i)+'"><input id = "any'+(i)+'"</td></tr>'
                     +
   '<tr id = "srok'+(++i)+'"><td>От '+ (something) +' дней и выше</td><td id = "td'+(i)+'"><input id = any'+i+"</td></tr>");
   var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
   elements[1].parentNode.removeChild(elements[1]);
   for(var t = 0 ; t<$("#neznayu td").length;t++)
  {
    if(t>1) $("#neznayu td")[t].remove();
  }
if(tedeus>0)  tedeus--;
for(var t = 0 ; t<=i;t++)
  {
    for(var h = 0;h<$("#srok"+t+" td").length;h++)
    {
    if(h>1) $("#srok"+t+" td input")[h].remove();
    }
  }*/
});

$("#adsumm").click(function() {
  var interv = prompt("Введите интервал сумм", 1);

  if (srabator == 0) {
    $("#ted" + tedeus).html("От 1 до " + interv);
    srabator++;
  }
  var someth2 = parseInt(interv) + 1;
  $("#ted" + tedeus).after("<td id ='ted" + (++tedeus) + "'> от " + someth2 + " и больше");
  var mmm = tedeus - 1;
  for (var mm = 1; mm <= i + 1; mm++) {
    $("#srok" + mm + "td" + mmm).after("<td id = 'srok" + i + "td" + (tedeus) + "' ><input  type ='text'></td");
  }

  /*for(var t = 0 ; t<=i;t++)
    {
      for(var h = 0;h<$("#srok"+t+" td").length;h++){
      if(h>2) $("#srok"+t+" td")[h].remove();
      }
    }

   for(var t = 0 ; t<$("#neznayu td").length;t++)
    {
      if(t>2) $("#neznayu td")[t].remove();
    }  
    
    
  */
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="neznayu">
    <td> </td>

    <td id="ted1">Для любой суммы</td>
    <th><a id="adsumm" href="#">Добавить интервал сумм</a></th>

  </tr>
  <tr id="srok1">
    <td>На любой срок </td>
    <td id="srok1td1"> <input type="text" id="any1" value=0 .4></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="summ">
    <td><a id="ad" href="#">добавить интервал сроков</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="otvet">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, вы сбивали нумерацию строк при добавлении строки в таблицу, из-за чего они просто ехали.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исправляем так, что бы у нулевого столбца не было `id`.

```
$('#srok'+i).after("<tr id ='srok"+(++i)+"'> <td> Ot "+a+"  do "+b+" dney</td><td id = 'srok"+i+"td"+i2+"'><input ></td>"  + "</tr>");
for(i2 = 1 ; i2<tedeus;i2++)
{
  $("#srok"+i+"td"+i2).after("<td id = 'srok"+i+"td"+(i2+1)+"'><input ></td>");
}
```

И во-вторых, вы не проводили итерацию по строкам, так как подставляли `i` который не меняется вместо mm.

```
$("#srok"+mm+"td"+mmm).after("<td id = 'srok"+mm+"td"+(tedeus)+"' ><input  type ='text'></td");}
```

А еще лучше избавиться от глобальных переменных и обращаться к элементам динамически. Но это уже вы сами, рабочий вариант на данный момент ниже.

```js
var  i =  1;  
var i2 = 1;
var srabator = 0 ;
var tedeus = 1;
var cp = tedeus;
$("#ad").click(function()
               {
  var  a = prompt("От скольких дней ?",0);
  var b = prompt("До скольких дней?",1);
  
 var something = parseInt(a)+1;
 $('#srok'+i).after("<tr id ='srok"+(++i)+"'> <td> Ot "+a+"  do "+b+" dney</td><td id = 'srok"+i+"td"+i2+"'><input ></td>"  + "</tr>");
for(i2 = 1 ; i2<tedeus;i2++)
    {
      $("#srok"+i+"td"+i2).after("<td id = 'srok"+i+"td"+(i2+1)+"'><input ></td>");
    }
  i2 = 1;
  
  
 /* $('#srok'+i).after('<tr id = "srok'+(++i)+'"><td>От 1 до '+a+' дней</td><td id = "td'+(i)+'"><input id = "any'+(i)+'"</td></tr>'
                     +
   '<tr id = "srok'+(++i)+'"><td>От '+ (something) +' дней и выше</td><td id = "td'+(i)+'"><input id = any'+i+"</td></tr>");
   var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
   elements[1].parentNode.removeChild(elements[1]);
   for(var t = 0 ; t<$("#neznayu td").length;t++)
  {
    if(t>1) $("#neznayu td")[t].remove();
  }
if(tedeus>0)  tedeus--;
for(var t = 0 ; t<=i;t++)
  {
    for(var h = 0;h<$("#srok"+t+" td").length;h++)
    {
    if(h>1) $("#srok"+t+" td input")[h].remove();
    }
  }*/
});

$("#adsumm").click(function()
{ var interv = prompt("Введите интервал сумм",1);

 if(srabator==0){ $("#ted"+tedeus).html("От 1 до " + interv); srabator++;}
 var someth2 = parseInt(interv)+1;
 $("#ted"+tedeus).after("<td id ='ted"+(++tedeus)+"'> от "+someth2+" и больше");
  var mmm = tedeus-1;
 for(var mm = 1 ; mm<=i+1;mm++){
$("#srok"+mm+"td"+mmm).after("<td id = 'srok"+mm+"td"+(tedeus)+"' ><input  type ='text'></td");}
 
/*for(var t = 0 ; t<=i;t++)
  {
    for(var h = 0;h<$("#srok"+t+" td").length;h++){
    if(h>2) $("#srok"+t+" td")[h].remove();
    }
  }

 for(var t = 0 ; t<$("#neznayu td").length;t++)
  {
    if(t>2) $("#neznayu td")[t].remove();
  }  
  
  
  СО ВТОРОГО РАЗА ВЫДАЕТ ПОЛНУЮ ХУЕТУ!!! РАЗОБРАТЬСЯ
*/ 
});
```

```css
td{border:1px solid black;}
table{border:1px solid black;}
tr{border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id = "neznayu">
    <td> </td>

    <td id = "ted1">Для любой суммы</td>
    <th><a id = "adsumm" href = "#">Добавить интервал сумм</a></th>

  </tr>
  <tr id = "srok1">
    <td>На любой срок </td>
    <td id = "srok1td1"> <input type = "text" id = "any1" value = 0.4></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id = "summ">
    <td><a id = "ad" href= "#">добавить интервал сроков</a></td></tr>
</table>
<div id = "otvet">
</div>
```

Comment: большое спасибо, ошибки понял, больше не повторятся)))